# git clone fails silently

Tags: git, github, git-clone

To be more precise, I believe "git clone" succeeds, but immediately deletes all the files in my resulting local repo. A similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361322/git-status-for-cloned-repository-shows-file-deleted), but I couldn't think of a way to phrase my twist on the question as an answer, so here I am.

Here's the rundown on the specifics of my scenario:

I have a repository on github. I am able to clone this repository as anyone would expect using git on Ubuntu 12.04. The problem arises when I try to clone the wiki (github makes this accessible via https://github.com/<owner>/<repository>.wiki.git). My resulting local copy is empty. Upon running "git status" I notice that the contents of the repo were deleted by some entity immediately after cloning.

On branch master

Changes to be committed:

(use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)

deleted: <filename>

...And so on for all the rest of the pages in my wiki.

"git branch -a" returns the same thing for me as for the other guy:

*master

remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master

remotes/origin/master

**update 1**

It's true I was not aware of the difference between the staging area and the working directory, but it seems that was not the issue. On the other hand, it may have revealed a bit more of what is wrong.

I forgot to mention that when I first clone the repository, I get the message "cannot stat <long_filename>: filename too long"

When I run "git reset" all of the deletions are listed under "unstaged changes after reset:". The odd one out is <long_filename> which is listed as a merge instead of a deletion. Still, no files are visible in the directory I cloned to after the reset.

**update 2**

I can view all the wiki entries that should be present by using gitk from the cloned folder, but I am quite certain that the files are not present in a raw format anywhere on my filesystem, otherwise "find / -name <filename> 2>/dev/null" should return some useful output.

**update 3**

Apparently one of my filenames is too long for git to manage. Checking out the repo again after cloning it got all the files but that one:
`error: unable to create file <filename>.md (File name too long)`

Comment: Please provide the actual repository URL, so that people can try cloning it themselves.

Comment: I understand that is helpful in many cases, but the wiki is part of a private repository.
I can confirm that other people with access to the wiki have managed to clone it, although they do so through GUI based applications. I have also met with success when I browse the repo via gitk, but I still cannot find the articles in my filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git checkout .` should discard all local changes since the last commit, reverting you back to a clean state.

Comment: That's interesting. I tried your suggestion and got the following error:
`error: unable to create file <filename>.md (File name too long)`
Could this be causing git to silently delete all my files?

Comment: Took me a while to remember that I should look for the other files, but the rest did end up appearing in my repo. That single file is still being a jerk but I can just change the name in the wiki. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that, in addition of failing silently, your empty folder, if created *before* the clone (and not created by the clone) would be removed as well.

In your case, the failure was because of a filename too long.
But, more generally, "`git clone $there $her`e" is allowed even when here directory exists as long as it is an empty directory, but the command incorrectly
removed it upon a failure of the operation.
That part has been fixed with Git 2.16.x/2.17 (Q1 2018)

See [commit d45420c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d45420c1c8612f085f1901c33ff6f0ccfbb72d3b), [commit f9e377a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f9e377adc0b1ed06e35d2c77a6c9f2687c5b950b), [commit 8486b84](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8486b84f0ea4d7f943fdbe81050553d69d198742), [commit a4c4efd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a4c4efd25159a8b308f9e204bc87e37b963bc2ae) (02 Jan 2018) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit addd37c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/addd37cd64e109eb0224e522869962519224cc78), 23 Jan 2018)</sup>

> ### `clone`: do not clean up directories we didn't create

> Once upon a time, `git-clone` would refuse to write into a directory that it did not itself create. The cleanup routines for a failed clone could therefore just remove the git and worktree dirs completely.
>
> In [55892d2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55892d23981917aefdb387ad7d0429f90cbd446a) (Allow cloning to an existing empty directory,
> 2009-01-11, Git v1.6.2-rc0), we learned to write into an existing directory.
> Which means that doing:
>
> ```
> mkdir foo
> git clone will-fail foo
> ```
>
> ends up deleting `foo`.
> This isn't a huge catastrophe, since by definition `foo` must be empty.
> But it's somewhat confusing; we should leave the filesystem as we found it.

---

"[`git clone --separate-git-dir=$elsewhere`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f175e9b845a41f1a5135222d4d3b8aa9161b499a/Documentation/git-clone.txt#L287)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---separate-git-dirltgitdirgt))</sup> used to stomp on the contents of the existing directory `$elsewhere`, which has been taught to fail when `$elsewhere` is not an empty directory with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020).

See [commit dfaa209](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dfaa209a79a831e8ff4f6b8e14a8b0c35b4f6b6e) (10 Jul 2020) by [Ben Wijen (`bwijen`)](https://github.com/bwijen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f175e9b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f175e9b845a41f1a5135222d4d3b8aa9161b499a), 30 Jul 2020)</sup>

> ### [`git clone`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dfaa209a79a831e8ff4f6b8e14a8b0c35b4f6b6e): don't clone into non-empty directory
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ben Wijen</sup>

> When using [`git clone`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/dfaa209a79a831e8ff4f6b8e14a8b0c35b4f6b6e/Documentation/git-clone.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone))</sup> with `--separate-git-dir realgitdir` and `realgitdir` already exists, it's content is destroyed.
>
> So, make sure we don't clone into an existing non-empty directory.
>
> When [d45420c1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d45420c1c8612f085f1901c33ff6f0ccfbb72d3b) ("`clone`: do not clean up directories we didn't create", 2018-01-02, Git v2.17.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/addd37cd64e109eb0224e522869962519224cc78) listed in [batch #1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5be1f00a9a701532232f57958efab4be8c959a29)) tightened the clean-up procedure after a failed cloning into an empty directory, it assumed that the existing directory given is an empty one so it is OK to keep that directory, while running the clean-up procedure that is designed to remove everything in it (since there won't be any, anyway).
> Check and make sure that the `$GIT_DIR` is empty even cloning into an existing repository.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not familiarized with the difference between the staging area and the working directory.

If all the files show as deleted that simply means there's a difference between your staging area and the working directory; specifically; the files are in the staging area but not on your working directory.

Just do `git reset`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this and updated my question to reflect new information.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX Mountain Lion, I had the error

```
error: Untracked working tree file '.DS_Store' would be overwritten by merge.
```

Apparantly the irritating .DS_Store file created my OSX's finder was in my remote repository that I was trying to clone. This was because I had initially pushed the project before updating the .gitignore file on my main computer.

Removing the .DS_Store from the remote repository before git cloning to my secondary computer fixed this for me. This is how I did it from my primary computer:

```
$   git rm .DS_Store 
$   git commit -m "removed .DS_Store"
$   git push
```