# TFS Git visual studio 2013 repo corruption or of behavior

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

We recently moved to TFS 2013 on premise using a Git team project.
I'm on the latest - vs 2013 update 3.

I have a particular folder path ( let's call it /home/test) that seems corrupted. There are files and sub folders in it.

We've tried adding the folder however it it shows up in the untracked area. I try and add it in visual studio but nothing happens when I click add all.

So I thought ok I'll drop into Git command line and check it in there. Git status is clean. So I added the files committed and pushed. And Git status says everything worked and is now clean again.

In TFS website everything appears there. However the test directory still marked as untracked in the visual studio UI.

When someone else pulls the repo the test folder and files are marked for deleted. No other commits. I even did a clean clone of the whole repo again and same thing. VS says test folder is not tracked. All the files are marked for deletion. Weird part is command line says everything is fine.

I thought it might be related to my Git ignore file but commented out everything and still the same. Anyone seen anything like this and any advice in fixing it?

Comment: In command line, are you in a branch when you added, committed and pushed? Is that the same branch as the one you see after a clone? (like http://stackoverflow.com/q/10361322/6309)

Comment: Yes it's the master branch.